# Send Email with read-only fields in Android

Tags: android, email, readonly

My app has a Contact Us section, where a user can send an email.  Some fields are pre-populated and need to be read-only, TO, SUBJECT.  Only the BODY is editable.

I am currently creating an intent as below to launch an email client on the device.

```
Intent sendIntent;

sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "test@test.com");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test Subject");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Even a stopped clock tells the right time twice a day.");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send Mail"));
```

Is it possible to make fields read-only, or do I have to create my own module, more along the lines of a 'form', and send the email in the background.

cheers

Comment: i also want this to be done...have you solved your problem..plz help me also..how to accomplish it